# VB error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible accepts this number of arguements

Tags: vb.net

I can't seem to get past this error that appears with this code block:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce", True).SetValue("cmd /C")
```

The full error is as follows:

```
BC30516 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET Overload resolution failed because no accessible accepts this number of arguments.
```

Looked all over for solutions and none seem to exist or work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.setValue()` needs another paramater: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSubKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.opensubkey?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_OpenSubKey_System_String_System_Boolean_) returns a [Registry​Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [SetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_SetValue_System_String_System_Object_) needs at least 2 parameters. You are only passing one. There are good example in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at the documentation but still can't work out what I need for the second parameter.

Comment: @StormDev you need to pass the name and the value. Seems like "cmd /C" is the value, you'll need to figure out the name.

Comment: The first parameter should be a string that is the name .. for example "RunCmd","cmd /C". If the key doesn't exist, it will be created, however, having tried that myself, I get a `SecurityException` - Requested registry access not allowed. So.. you'll need to sort that out I suspect :-)